# i18next-icu is not supporting {{ (double brackets) while translating in react

Tags: reactjs, i18next

I am building a react app using pretty standard facebooks create-react-app

I am using i18next to support localization, also I need pluralization and I am using ICU as to support pluralization and here is example of ICU format for supporting pluralization.

```
"VALID_FOR_DAYS": "{count, plural, one{Valid for {count} more day} other{Valid for {count} more days}}",
```

Here is my i18 configuration in my react project

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import I18nextIcu from 'i18next-icu';

const icu = new I18nextIcu();


export const initilizeLocaleSettings = async (defaultLocale: string): Promise<void> => {
       await i18n
        .use(icu)
        .use(initReactI18next)
        .init({
            resources: {
                en: {
                    translation: {
                        WELCOME: 'Welcome {{name}}',
                        VALID_FOR_DAYS": "{count, plural, one{Valid for {count} more day} other{Valid for {count} more days}}",
                    }
                }
            },
            lng: defaultLocale,
            fallbackLng: defaultLocale,
            interpolation: {
                escapeValue: false
            }
        });
};
```

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

function App() {
    const { t } = useTranslation();

    return (
        <h1>
            {t('VALID_FOR_DAYS', { count: 10 })}
            {t('WELCOME', { name: 'JOHN DOE' })}
        </h1>
    );
}
```

pluralization works fine **VALID_DAYS** gets traslated perfectly
but **WELCOME** doesn't it gives me following error

`SyntaxError: Expected "0", [1-9] or [^ \t\n\r,.+={}#] but "{" found.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appreciate this is a while ago, but you dont need the double curly brackets:

this:

```
translation: {
                        WELCOME: 'Welcome {{name}}',
                        VALID_FOR_DAYS": "{count, plural, one{Valid for {count} more day} other{Valid for {count} more days}}",
                    }
```

should be:

```
translation: {
                        WELCOME: 'Welcome {name}',
                        VALID_FOR_DAYS": "{count, plural, one{Valid for {count} more day} other{Valid for {count} more days}}",
                    }
```